# Multiple module, api / implementation gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I use spring boot 3 with gradle

I have this structure

```
pro
├── intranet
│   ├── src
│   ├── gradle
│   └── build.gradle
├── extranet
│   ├── src
│   ├── gradle
│   └── build.gradle
├── common
│   ├── src
│   ├── gradle
│   └── build.gradle
├── .gradle
│   ├── gradle.properties
│   └── 
└── settings.gradle
└── build.gradle
└── readme.md
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'lcm'
include 'intranet'
include 'extranet'
include 'common'
```

global build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.acme.lcm-backend'
version '0.0.24-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
}
```

No sure if at that level jar need to be enabled? also only common is a java-library

Tried without this global.build and project compile also. Any advantage to have it?

build.gradle of intranet

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.acme.lcm-intranet'
version = '1.0.20-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

ext {
    set('springCloudAzureVersion', "5.0.0")
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
api 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.4'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation project(':common') // root project -> settings.gradle
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:${springCloudAzureVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

build.gradle of common

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
//    id 'java-library'
}

group = 'com.acme.lcm-common'
version = '1.0.20-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'


compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
   
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final'

    runtimeOnly group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc11', version: '21.9.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named("bootJar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.named("jar") {
    enabled = true
}
```

In common i found i can build without issue with java and java-library plugin any reason?

Intranet and Extranet need to generate a jar. Theses both project need to use common jar

Actually project build, but I don't know if the structure follow good pratice.

Intranet use api for both dependencies, i tried with implementation and that work also

I have not fully understand the utility of api, implementation in gradle

Answer (score -1):

#### Better Structuring

You can try multi-project for structuring build and `buildSrc` to organize build logic. Most of the modern Java projects apply these two things in Gradle. The easiest way to construct one is to use the init command provided by Gradle:

```bash
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------
...

$ gradle init
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Select type of project to generate:
  1: basic
  2: application
  3: library
  4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 2

Select implementation language:
  1: C++
  2: Groovy
  3: Java
  4: Kotlin
  5: Scala
  6: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..6] 3

Generate multiple subprojects for application? (default: no) [yes, no] yes
Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy
  2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Groovy) [1..2] 1

Project name (default: a): demo
Source package (default: demo): com.example
Enter target version of Java (min. 7) (default: 17): 17
Generate build using new APIs and behavior (some features may change in the next minor release)? (default: no) [yes, no] no

> Task :init
Get more help with your project: https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/samples/sample_building_java_applications_multi_project.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 35s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

By looking carefully at this minimal project, you will know how it works:

```bash
$ tree -L 2 .
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── buildSrc
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── list
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── settings.gradle
└── utilities
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
```

Since your common module `common` contains Spring Boot dependencies, you should read this https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/ also.

References:

- https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

#### API vs Implementation

They determine the dependency visibility at **compile time**.

Assume a module `A` depends on a module `B`, and the module `B` depends on a module `C`.

If you want `A` to be able to use `C`'s elements at compile time, then put `api("C")` in `B`'s `build.gradle`.

If you want `C` to be internally used in `B` only, then put `implementation("C")` in `B`'s `build.gradle`.

References:

- https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

Comment: i checked the link of spring multimodule, but i don't understand why the library have a dependencies on spring-boot-starter, but not the application. Also for my case the use of api is useless and everything should use implementation